Django. Как показать разновидность товара?
При создании интернет-магазина возник вопрос: как отображать такой же товар, только другой модификации? Допустим, у меня есть корм для собак с лососем 0.4кг, также есть такой же товар, только с индейкой на 0.6 и 0.8кг. Как производить фильтрацию и отображать данные вариации? Хочу видеть товар и кнопочки с выбором вкуса и веса.
